# How to reduce the font size while print notepad file from DOS using BAT file

Tags: batch-file, c#, ms-dos, notepad

I am using DOS BAT file for print text file(bill).The problem is font size is too large so, its not fit in the paper size.The BAT Code is

`copy bill.txt \\127.0.0.1\bill
exit`

please explain how to reduce the font size.
And I am using c# for write in text file

Comment: What printer?  Which printer driver?  What have you tried already?

Comment: i am using c# to write in text file and using BAT file to print...
the printer is connected with USB Port so, i am using the above code for print.The problem is font size of text file.Its too large

Comment: What font? Text file has no font in it, only the content. And why should you use DOS to print while Windows has already provided much more featured print service

Comment: i am printing from c# windows application in roll paper @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: Then just use the printing service from the program, no need for any *.bat file

Comment: here the printing is not an issue.font size is the problem

Comment: You can specify font size, page size and many thing else with the printing service

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the printer supports printing of command-codes (for example PCL). Most middle- & high-end printers do support printing of PCL.

Before printing the text you need to send the commands to the printer to switch to a smaller font. You could even switch to landscape with commands (but that's probably not wanted with a bill).

For most printers the standard font should be "Courier 12cpi". You can switch to a more condensed font of 17cpi. (For PCL you can find the commands [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=bpl02705))

You need to make a small textfile `small.txt` with the following code:

```
<Esc>&k2S
```

You need to replace the `<Esc>` with the actual escape character (being 0x1B or character 27).

You can print your bill like this:

```
copy small.txt+bill.txt \\127.0.0.1\bill
exit
```

You could even switch to a proportional font like "Univers" (this is like "Arial") and set the font size:

```
<Esc>(s1p10v52T
```

The `(s1p` stands for proportional printing, the `10v` for the font size and `52T` stands for "Univers". With this method you can choose the exact font-size. With the previous "Courier" you only have 10, 12 and 17 cpi.

I should note however that normal textfiles align their text with spaces and expect every character to be the same width so if there are columns in the file they won't align properly.

**Edit**: If you don't have an editor which supports escape codes you can do the following (but you could have written a small c# program):

Make a textfile with the following (call it `small.vbs`):

```
Wscript.Stdout.Write Chr(27)+"&k2S"
```

Then execute the following on a command prompt:

```
cscript /nologo small.vbs > small.txt
```

This will result in a `small.txt` file which you can use with the copy command.

**Edit 2**: It just occured to me to me that if it's not the **width** that a problem but the **height** of the text then you have no use switching to 17cpi because that still prints 6 lines per inch. Then you should switch your printer to 8 lines per inch with the following command:

```
<Esc>&l8D
```

So then adjust above method with cscipt. (change the `"&k2S"` in `&l8D`.)
You could also do both (17cpi and 8 lines per inch)

```
<Esc>&k2S<Esc>&l8D
```

so make the `small.txt` like this:

```
Wscript.Stdout.Write Chr(27)+"&k2S"+Chr(27)+"&l8D"
```

Comment: please explain this <Esc>

Comment: `<Esc>` should be just one character. For example `A` is character hexidecimal `0x41` or `65`. Normally you could do `Alt+65` to get the `A` but for most editors `Alt+27` won't work because they don't support anything under `0x20`. What kind of editor do you use ?? If it supports hex-mode you can do it in there.

Comment: before that what is the use of it?

Comment: I added a method to create the `small.txt` with cscript in my answer. But you could also have done this in c#. (I didn't understand your comment "before that what is the use of it?". The use of printing `small.txt` before your `bill.txt` is switching the printer over to a more condensed font.)

Comment: ok ok I will check....

Comment: The <esc> is a code that is combined with other characters, to tell the printer that it is receiving a control code.  <esc> is 027 in ASCII, but your text editor should be capable of handling the character even though it is not generally visible.  When it is visible, it is displayed as a $. Rik's answer was comprehensive and helpful. The only easier way might be to change the default font on the printer itself.

Comment: Rik, most printers in the last 10+ years default to Times Roman rather than Courier;  the latter is vastly deprecated these days.

Answer (score -1):

A lot would depend on the file itself. If your text file was designed for a landscape width and you are printing in portrait mode then the file would not fit properly.

If you are opening the file in notepad then you can select the Format menu, then select Font to change the font size.

Using the Format menu in Notepad will also give you the wordwrap option. This might also make a difference but could impact the output if you are epecting a specific spacing, alignment etc.

You might need to print in Landscape instead of Portrait depending on the width of the text contained within your file.

Comment: He's sending a text file to a shared printer via `Copy`. None of this applies.

Comment: its not a problem in landscape or portrait. need to reduce the font size.that is important

Comment: That's not a shared printer. The printer is connected to the USB port. And 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, so copys a file like that only has effect when there's a server listening on port 80